# JavaFX ToolBar Drop Shadow Effect and Mouse Events

Tags: javafx

If I add a Drop Shadow Effect to a ToolBar, the ToolBar occupies more space, which is unacceptable in my case.. Is there any way to prevent the drop shadow taking extra space or ignore the mouse events on the drop shadow area? Or do I have to try another route to "add drop shadow to a toolbar"?

**EDIT:** `setPickOnBounds(false)` is a step in the right direction (I guess), but the drop shadow still consumes the events.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I circumvented this by having a StackPane on top of my main content view, and adding a Region to the top of it, just below the ToolBar..